# issues when adding a predictor in MGCA

Tags: r, lme4

I'm using MCGA to predict the effects of my protocole through times on some outcomes. For example let's say Self-Esteem (GSE in my database). Self-esteem have been measured over 5 times. Last note, sujet is similaire to ID

Three basics models are working with this code

`c0 <- lmer(GSE~ 1 + (1|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

`c1 <- lmer(GSE~ time + (time|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

`c2 <- lmer(GSE~ poly(time, 2, raw = TRUE) + (poly(time, 2, raw = TRUE)|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

I would like to enrich my model in adding the effect of the relationship between the therapist and the patient (i.e., ALLIANCE in my data base) (from patient point of view) to see if predict better self-esteem level. So, my code is like this and works BUT I have no idea of the pertinence of the c2 and c3 model:

`c0 <- lmer(GSE~ 1 + (1|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

`c1 <- lmer(GSE~ ALLIANCE + (ALLIANCE|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

`c2 <- lmer(GSE~ time*ALLIANCE + (time*ALLIANCE|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

`c3 <- lmer(GSE~ poly(time*ALLIANCE, 2, raw = TRUE) + (poly(time*ALLIANCE, 2, raw = TRUE)|sujet), date = X3PHRMI`

So, the first problem is that I don't know if my model c2 and c3 are pertinent ? I know that in simple regression the formula is like Y = bO + b1 +b2 + errors

The second issues is that I'm not sure if the shape of my data base is correct and so it might misleading my results... Indeed we measure self-esteem 5 times per subject but we measure ALLIANCE only one time (in that case ALLIANCE is like a categorical variable). When I'm running the previous model with only one measure of alliance I got this error :

Error : number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: sujet)

So, I decided to set my database as following:

| sujet | time | GSE | ALLIANCE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 26 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 29 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 32 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 | 34 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 18 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 22 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 25 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 22 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 24 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 24 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 25 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | 29 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 26 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 28 | 2 |

I tried to set "sujet" and "alliance "as.factor" but I got the same errors.

I'm a beginner in using that kind of analysis so I might do stupid mistakes. I seek help with "coworkers" but they just apply the code as our "superior" give us.
So I'm here to get some explanations if someone is willing to explain.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sloved the problem by creating two categories thanks to the median.
For example median = 3.5
All the person < 3.5 will be the category 1 ; >3.5 category 2